# Mathematical Logic Sentence

Tags: logic

I have a Language, $L$,  that consists of a unary function symbol $f$. I have two domains, $A_1$ which is $\mathbb N$ and $B_1$ which is $\mathbb Z$ where in $A_1$, $f$ sends $x_1$ to $x_1+1$ and in $B_1$, $f$ sends $x_1$ to $x_1+2$.

I need to write a sentence of the Language which is true in $A_1$ but not is $B_1$. I want to show that the function is not surjective in $\mathbb N$ as you cannot get $0$, but is surjective is $\mathbb Z$.

I'm finding it very difficult to express this in a sentence of $L$.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express that $f$ *is* surjective as follows:

$$\forall x \ \exists y \ x = f(y)$$

So, to express that $f$ is not surjective, simply negate this:

$$\neg \forall x \ \exists y \ x = f(y)$$

or, equivalently:

$$\exists x \ \forall y \ x \not = f(y)$$

Comment: I didn't think I could use $x$ the variable on its own since $x$ is not part of the language

Comment: @juper Sure you can: all variables are part of the logic language, just as much as the quantifiers and other logical operators are.

Comment: ah yes. Thanks for you help on this!

Comment: @juper Different question -> different post! (and make sure to indicate how $f$ works in $\mathbb{Q}$)